# Why do I get a SEGFAULT while decrementing the stack pointer in my MIPS assembly code for Linux?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I've decided to write a Pacman game in MIPS (little-endian) assembly language for linux for the terminal (just for fun). However, I've recently run into a quite strange error that I've never encountered before: I get a SEGFAULT while decrementing the stack pointer. The error occurs in a function labeled initializeScreen:

```
initializeScreen: 
    #Save return address
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, ($sp)

    #Save s registers
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $s0, ($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $s1, ($sp)
    
    #Initialize screen. 
    #Step #1: Clear the screen. 
    #Step #2: Display the high score, current level, and points. 
    #Step #3: Draw the maze. 
    #Step #4: Draw pacman. 
    #Step #5: Draw the ghosts. 
    #Step #6: Draw the power pellets. 
    #Step #7: Display the number of lives remaining. 

    #Step #1: Clear the screen. 
    la $a0, buffer
    #jal storeClearToString
    lw $t8, 76($s7)
    jalr $t8

    addi $a0, $a0, 4
    #jal storeRTOToString
    lw $t8, 80($s7)
    jalr $t8

    #Print
    addi $a0, $zero, 1
    la $a1, buffer
    addi $a2, $zero, 8
    addi $v0, $zero, 4004
    syscall

    #Step #2: Display the high score, current level, and points. 
    #Current level (1st byte)
    #Print the text
    addi $a0, $zero, 1
    la $a1, levelText
    addi $a2, $zero, 15
    addi $v0, $zero, 4004
    syscall
    #Print the number
    lw $s0, 0($s6)
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    addi $t1, $zero, 24
    sll $a0, $a0, $t1
    srl $a0, $a0, $t1
    #jal printInt
    lw $t8, 24($s7)
    jal $t8

    #Print '\n'
    addi $a0, $zero, 1
    la $a1, newline2
    addi $a2, $zero, 1
    addi $v0, $zero, 4004
    syscall

    #High score (2nd byte)
    #Note for the future: Might want to allocate more memory for the scores. 
    #Print the text
    addi $a0, $zero, 1
    la $a1, highScoreText
    addi $a2, $zero, 12
    addi $v0, $zero, 4004
    syscall
    #Print the number
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    addi $t1, $zero, 16
    sll $a0, $a0, $t1
    addi $t1, $zero, 24
    srl $a0, $a0, $t1
    #jal printInt
    lw $t8, 24($s7)
    jal $t8

    #Print '\n'
    addi $a0, $zero, 1
    la $a1, newline2
    addi $a2, $zero, 1
    addi $v0, $zero, 4004
    syscall

    #Number of points (4th byte)
    #Print the text
    addi $a0, $zero, 1
    la $a1, pointsCollText
    addi $a2, $zero, 18
    addi $v0, $zero, 4004
    syscall
    #Print the number
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    addi $t1, $zero, 24
    srl $a0, $a0, $t1
    #jal printInt
    lw $t8, 24($s7)
    jal $t8

    #Print '\n'
    addi $a0, $zero, 1
    la $a1, newline2
    addi $a2, $zero, 1
    addi $v0, $zero, 4004
    syscall

    #Step #3: Print the maze. 
    #Create the drawing array
    addi $a0, $zero, 10
    addi $a1, $zero, 10
    addi $a2, $zero, 4
    #jal createNewTwoDArray
    lw $t8, 44($s7)
    jalr $t8
    add $s0, $v0, $zero
    
    #Test: Print a rectangle. 
    #Create the Rectangle
    addi $a0, $zero, 7
    addi $a1, $zero, 7
    #jal createNewRectangle
    lw $t8, 92($s7)
    jalr $t8
    add $s1, $v0, $zero
    #Print it
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    add $a1, $zero, $zero
    add $a2, $zero, $zero
    add $a3, $zero, $zero
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $s1, ($sp)
    #jal drawRectangle
    lw $t8, 96($s7)
    jalr $t8

    #Exit:
    lw $s1, ($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $s0, ($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $ra, ($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

More specifically, it occurs here (the last instruction):

```
    #Print it
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    add $a1, $zero, $zero
    add $a2, $zero, $zero
    add $a3, $zero, $zero
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
```

At first I though that the program was running out of space in the `.text` section, but GDB gives me the following output:

```
(gdb) x/6iw $pc
=> 0x400e88 <initializeScreen+432>:     addi    sp,sp,-4
   0x400e8c <initializeScreen+436>:     sw  s1,0(sp)
   0x400e90 <initializeScreen+440>:     lw  t8,96(s7)
   0x400e94 <initializeScreen+444>:     nop
   0x400e98 <initializeScreen+448>:     jalr    t8
   0x400e9c <initializeScreen+452>:     nop
```

My second thought was that I might have ran out of stack space. However, I know that the maximum stack size on Linux is on the order of either kilobytes or megabytes and unlike code generated by the GNU C compiler, my assembly code only uses the stack for storing register values. Therefore, It's unlikely that I've ran out of stack space.

Also, the value of $sp is `0x407fff7c`.

Comment: Where do you restore the value of `$sp` so that `lw $ra, ($sp)` loads the correct return address?

Comment: Also, does your target CPU have branch delay slots? If so, having an `lw $ra, ($sp)` right after a `jalr` looks suspicious.

Comment: @Michael, I don't get why I would need to restore the value of `$sp`. In every function that `initializeScreen` calls, I make sure that the value of `$sp` before the function is called is equal to the value of `$sp` after the function returns (except I forgot to do that in initializeScreen and fixed that, but the main problem still remains).

Comment: Also, @Michael, the reason I use `lw $t8, x($s7)` and `jalr $t8` is because I have had a situation where two files included the same file and then those two files where being included by another file (using the `.include` directive) which gave me errors. I figured that the best sollution would be to in the `main` function, create a giant array that holds the addresses of all the functions and store it's base address in `$s7`. Then, to call a function, I'd load the address of that function from the array in `$s7` into `$t8` and do `jalr $t8`. It works, but not sure if it's the best sollution.

Comment: Also, so far, I've only studied for 1 year at university and only had 1 course that talked about assembly language (which was titled "Computer Organization"). That couse used the MARS simulator and only taught the basics of assembly programming such as the MIPS instructions, floating-point numbers, how a CPU does multiplication and division, and how computer memory works. To program in MIPS for Linux, I had to do my own reading outside of class and experimentation.

Comment: If by decrement the stack pointer, you literally mean using an add I-Type instruction on the stack pointer register, then there's no way that such an instruction can segfault.  Only memory reference instructions (loads & stores for data & branches for code) can segfault.

Comment: When working with any pointer arithmetic including decrementing and incrementing the stack pointer, use `addiu` and `addu` instead of `addi` and `add`.  This is because pointers and pointer arithmetic is unsigned and the `u` versions of the instruction don't check for signed overflow, where as the non-`u` versions do, and checking for signed overflow on address arithmetic is erroneous, and so should not be done.

Comment: There's an extra push right before the call to `drawRectangle`, near the bottom of the function, but there's no corresponding pop for it, so probably unbalances the stack and then the exit/return code messes up.  My guess is the `jr $ra` faults because the stack has 4 pushes but only 3 pops, so isn't popping what was pushed and the `jr $ra` is the first to notice the problem by attempting to use the bogus `$ra` value, as it is instead really a saved `$s0` value.  Look more closely at the actual segfault error, it should contain some additional information; use gdb if you need to.

Comment: @Michael: The default for GAS might be `.set reorder`, where the assembler fills branch delay slots for you, making them invisible in the asm source.  (And apparently also load delay slots if set for MIPS I; notice the OP's disassembly from GDB where a `nop` follows the `lw` and the `jalr`.)

Comment: `0x407fff7c` is near the top of a page, but not right at the top.  So if you're storing for every decrement (yuck, adjust SP once per function and use offsets relative to it), you'd have faulted at `0x407ffffc`, the top word of the page if the problem was running out of stack space.  But `0x407fff7c` is surprisingly close to your static code at `0x400e88`, and presumably your data.  On most architectures, Linux points the user-space stack pointer near the very top of the user part of virtual address space, so I'd have expected an SP value close to `0x7ffff000` with a 32-bit kernel.

Comment: What was the value of `$sp` when your program first started?  Was it anywhere near `0x407fff7c`?  I wonder if there's any kind of ABI requirement on keeping the stack pointer aligned, or any stack layout stuff that signal delivery might depend on?  (Did you do any `sigaction` system calls to install signal handlers?)  https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/mipsabi.pdf says highest stack address should be `0x7fffffff`, but I haven't read it in detail for other requirements.  It seems really old, like 1996, IDK if it's still current.

Answer (score 0):

Changing all occurrences of `addi $sp, $sp, -4` to `addiu $sp, $sp, -4` and `addi $sp, $sp, 4` to `addiu $sp, $sp, 4` solved the issue (I'll change my code later so that it offsets `$sp` once per function and uses offsets relative to it). Thanks, @Erik Eidt, @Michael, and @Peter Cordes.

Comment: Weird. If `$sp` actually was `0x407fff7c`, that's very far from the `0x80000000` to `0x7ffffffc` boundary for signed overflow.  And I'd have expected an arithmetic exception to raise SIGFPE not SIGSEGV.  (Can you check on your Linux MIPS system what signal you get when `li $t0, 0x80000000` ; `addi $t0, $t0, -4` traps on signed overflow?  POSIX says that if arithmetic raises an exception at all, it should be SIGFPE, but Linux doesn't always strictly follow POSIX.)

Comment: @Michael, I cannot do `li $t0, 0x80000000` because only the 1st 16 bits of `0x80000000` will be stored. In a test program, I did: `addi $t0, $zero, 1`; `addi $t1, $zero, 31`; `sll $t0, $t0, $t1`; `addi $t0, $t0, -4`, plus some code to exit. I ran this code in qemu (as I don't have a real MIPS cpu), and qemu printed `qemu: unhandled CPU exception 0x15 - aborting` plus the values of all of the registers, with the value of `$t0` being `0x80000000`. Note that this not a segmentation fault or bus error.

Comment: The only difference between `addi` and `addiu` is not faulting on signed integer overflow, so if that wasn't the symptom you were getting before, you actually had some other problem that you also fixed at the same time you made this change.

Comment: `li` is a pseudo-instruction that works with any constant.  `li $t0, 0x80000000` should assemble to `lui $t0, 0x8000`, not needing an `addiu` for the low half since it's zero.  But yes, materializing the constant in a much less efficient way still works.  (You know MIPS has immediate shifts, right, like `slli $t0, $t0, 31`?) Anyway, so you're not actually using Linux MIPS?  Like you used per-process QEMU instead of qemu-system-mips with a Linux kernel and user-space?  A real kernel would install fault handlers and deliver a signal to the offending user-space process.